# Which is better to compare dates < or DateDiff?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, date, datetime

Which is considered better?

```
select *
from TableA
where productDate < '12/9/2013'
```

or

```
select *
from TableA
where DATEDIFF(day, productDate, '12/9/2013') > 0
```

While skimming thru articles, I read that using Date functions (ex: datediff, dateadd) in where clauses affected performance negatively. Is this true?

Comment: The first one can make use of indexes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The best will likely be:

```
SELECT <column list> -- not * (1)
  FROM dbo.TableA -- please always specify schema (2)
  WHERE productDate < '20131209'; -- always use a semi-colon (3)
    -- and always use a non-regional, unambiguous date format (4)
```

The reason this will be best is because it gives the optimizer the best chance to use an index on the `productDate` column. Even if an index doesn't exist today, someone may add one tomorrow. Applying functions like `DATEDIFF()` to the column will *always* make the expression non-sargable, meaning it will *always* have to use a less efficient scan (assuming that's the only search predicate).

As for the inline comments:

1. [Bad habits to kick : using SELECT * / omitting the column list](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/10/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-omitting-the-column-list)
2. [Bad habits to kick : avoiding the schema prefix](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/11/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix)
3. [Ladies and gentlemen, start your semi-colons!](https://sqlblog.org/2009/09/03/ladies-and-gentlemen-start-your-semi-colons)
4. [Bad habits to kick : mis-handling date / range queries](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries)

Comment: I was going to throw my head back and give a maniacal laugh and call you crazy for saying "always use semi-colons". However, after reading your article... I guess I should start using semi-colons. Learn something everyday.

Comment: @dotnetN00b yeah, it will definitely not be funny if Microsoft ever actually does enforce that rule. I doubt it will happen in our lifetime, but I'd rather be safe than sorry. It's not like it kills productivity to add them as you're writing the query...

Comment: Aaron is right and for the record any use of WHERE FUNCTION(T.Column) = @RESULT ill likely be RBAR (row by agonizing row) since engine ill need to evaluate each row. Try to invert it by using WHERE T.Column = INVERSE_FUNCTION(@RESULT) to speed up things.

Answer (score 2):

When you apply a function to a column you are unable to use any indexes available on this column.

Therefore the use of `DateDiff()` on the `productDate` will be less efficient than a less-than operator