# Date Comparison in TSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, sqldatetime

Why is it that each of the following returns records:

```
SELECT Name, CreatedDate 
FROM EmployeeTable 
WHERE CreatedDate < '20151214'

SELECT Name, CreatedDate 
FROM EmployeeTable 
WHERE CreatedDate > '20151214'
```

While the following query doesn't?

```
SELECT Name, CreatedDate 
FROM EmployeeTable 
WHERE CreatedDate = '20151214'
```

I had to use a `CAST` with the equality operator to get the results I wanted:

```
SELECT Name, CreatedDate 
FROM EmployeeTable 
WHERE CAST(CreatedDate as DATE) = '2015-12-14'
```

Is there any way to use the equality operator without having to use a cast?

`CreatedDate` is of type `DATETIME`, and includes times.

Comment: Is CreatedDate `DATE` or `DATETIME`?

Comment: @lad2025 yes it does -

Comment: So the answer is simple, you compare with `2015-12-14T00:00:00` and don't have exact match

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Probably `CreatedDate` contains a time part (e.g. is of type `datetime`). That's why the `=` doesn't work out of the box. When you cast it to `date` the time part is removed and then the `=` comparison works OK.

Comment: it does actually contain a time part (it is a datetime type) , but it works well with < and > but not with =

Comment: Well, the time part doesn't mess up the `<` or `>` comparisons. Think about it, it's normal. For example '20140101 3 PM' is still bigger than '20140101' but it's not equal to it.

Comment: If you have an index on `CreatedDate` the best way to execute the query is: `Select Name, CreatedDate from EmployeeTable where CreatedDate >= '20151214' and CreatedDate < '20151215'`, otherwise MSSQL will probably run a full table scan.

Answer (score 1):

`DATEDIFF` is the preferred way of checking equality of dates in SQL, unless you use the newer `DATE` type (instead of `DATETIME`).

Casting to `DATE` removes any time portion.

`DATEDIFF` is probably also more robust (than <>=)

Comment: AFAIK, DATEDIFF is slower, if we can use < or >, we'd better use them.

Comment: Actually I think its not slower, especially for equality testing.  DATEDIFF is optimized very well.  For <> you may be correct.  Unless you have some performance stats :)

Comment: I don't know. But I've read this in a good book.

Comment: @Grantly: do you have any references / benchmarks on `DATEDIFF` performance compared to other methods?

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20476637/which-is-better-to-compare-dates-or-datediff

Comment: This is one off the cuff, not very scientific nor conclusive.  http://www.ideaexcursion.com/2009/02/17/efficiently-query-the-date-in-datetime/ ... Not that the OP question is about speed, but having to CAST a string to a DATE or DATETIME inherently is adding more complexity.  DATEDIFF does this faster as you do not need the CAST

Comment: (Although I do tend to agree, for simplicity <> are better.  That DATEDIFF ignores indexes is surprising but possible.  For equality testing - to eliminate using a CAST - I think DATEDIFF would compare favourably)

Comment: Performance is not that good, see http://sqltouch.blogspot.se/2013/11/datediff-function-common-performance.html.  DATEADD might be a better option when used on the RHS.  (Better than using a CAST anyway)